# Conditional Sentences: "If I hadn't gone" or "If I didn't go"?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, phrase-choice

> If I **hadn't** gone to bed late yesterday, I wouldn't be tired now.
>
> If I **didn't** go to bed late yesterday, I wouldn't be tired now.

What is the correct way to express it, or are both possible?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ell stack exchage, Ro888.

Grammatically, both the sentences are correct.  However, they don't convey the same sense.

The verb in the if-clause of the first sentence is in the conditional subjunctive mood.  The use of the past perfect tense shows a situation that was counterfactual or hypothetical.

The verb in the if-clause of the second sentence is in the indicative mood.  It indicates a fact - a situation that is factual.

The first sentence  indicates a contrary-to-fact situation that you went to bed late, so  you will be tired now.

The second sentence indicates that you didn't go to bed late yesterday, so you will not tired now.

Answer (score 0):

I think *If I didn't go to bed late yesterday, I wouldn't be tired now.* is the "better" way to say it. By that I mean you could still use the former sentence but it is better to use the second one.

Why?

Because it uses *didn't* which refers to specifically not doing while the former sentence used *hadn't* which instead refers to many things together like:

Experiencing: *I had a great time*

Having a belonging In the past: *My father gave me a key and I had it all the way until I when I moved out where, I lost it*

Etc...

Comment: The OP's use of *hadn't* isn't a change of verb but a change in tense (from simple past to past participle). It is no less correct to use *hadn't* hear than it is to say, "I hadn't slept for days when I answered the phone." Notice that changing this example to "I didn't sleep" actually disturbs the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The correct phrasing is

> If I hadn't gone to bed late yesterday, I wouldn't be tired now.

There is an excellent explanation of the English conditional [here](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/). Your sentence is an example of a **mixed conditional**: a counterfactual (unreal) past condition with a speculated present outcome.

If you choose to write *didn't* instead, you imply that you don't know whether or not you truly went to bed late yesterday (in the source I linked, this is called a **type 2 conditional**). But you know for certain that you *did* go to bed late yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

Both mean the exact same thing and convey the message exactly the same.